# Cannot figure out iPhone/Objective-C Memory Leak in sqlite data retrieval

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, sqlite

I am trying to do some basic table retrieval from sqlite and I keep stumbling over some memory leak I cannot figure out, especially since it appears only with one of two equivalent lines.

What I do is simple :

-Create an object (category) to hold my sqlite DB line
-Have a method that queries sqlite and returns an array of these objetcs

I put all the code here (stripped it down a bit to simplify but the I have the memory leak with this very code).

category.h:

```
@interface Category : NSObject {
    int         catId;
    NSString    *description;
    int         order;
    NSString    *iconName;
}

@property(nonatomic, readwrite, assign) int catId;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *description;
@property(nonatomic, readwrite, assign) int order;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *iconName;


@end
```

category.m:

```
#import "Category.h"


@implementation Category

@synthesize catId;
@synthesize description;
@synthesize order;
@synthesize iconName;

@end
```

Method to retrieve array:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getAll {

    NSString *query = "select id, description, catorder, image from category order by catorder";
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    NSMutableArray  *categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2([[Database sharedDatabase] instance], [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            int     dbId =              sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            char    *dbDescription =    (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
            int     dbOrder =           sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);
            char    *dbIcon =           (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);

            NSString *desc = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:dbDescription];
            NSString *icon = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:dbIcon];          

            Category *category = [[Category alloc] init];

            category.catId=dbId;
            category.description = desc;
            //category.description = @"Test";
            category.order = dbOrder;
            category.iconName = icon;
            //category.icon = @"test.png";

            [desc release];         
            [icon release];

            [categoryArray addObject:category];

            [category release];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    [categoryArray autorelease];
    return categoryArray;
}
```

This line leaks

```
NSString *icon = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:dbIcon];
```

This line doesn't

```
NSString *desc = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:dbDescription];
```

Here what instruments shows :
[image]

and when I drill down :
[image]

Comment: What does the static analyzer tell you?

Comment: Try the following without release it: NSString *icon = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:dbIcon];

Comment: What does it say when you look for leaks in Instruments?

Comment: Static analyser stays mute :-( I added two images that displays what Instruments tells. I tried to replace alloc/init with the convenience method: if I keep the [icon release] as Franck suggested, the leak has vanished, but I remove [icon release] then it leaks again!!!

Comment: Are you sure the leak is coming from this code? Just because the string is *created* here, doesn't mean the leak is caused by this code. Compare the retain/release histories of the 2 strings (1 leaking, the other not) in Instruments and check if there are any unmatched retains in the leaking one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a dealloc method. You need to have this in your Category.m file:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [description release];
    [iconName release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Also, I'm pretty sure you can't have a property named "description".  That's a reserved method name.

Comment: Yep; - (NSString *)description is implemented in NSObject. "The debugger’s print-object command indirectly invokes this method to produce a textual description of an object." It's fine to replace its implementation in a subclass, but it's not a good choice for a property name.

Comment: So I got rid of the "description"(replaced with "label"), and added the -(void)dealloc that was obviously missing... and now what happens??? I don't even go any more to my nasty leak: after the call to my -getAll method (called in the -viewDidLoad method), I immediately go in this -dealloc and then my application crashes (...*** __NSAutoreleaseFreedObject(): release of previously deallocated object (0x4b1a3f0) ignored)... Looks like something else is going on here... I'm tying hard, but this is just so difficult to figure out :-(

Comment: OK, I think it finally works... and I quite understand it... Disregard my previous comment (while tinkering with [[NSString alloc] initWith...] vs. [NSString stringFrom...], I ended up with a release sent to the [NSString stringWith...] which then later was followed by the pool autorelease and hence a crash). So, now after I added the -dealloc it seems fine; no Leak, no crash. While digging, I found this very helpful link explaining how Instrument can help solving memory crashes (http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/)

Comment: Now, I am still not quite sure why the -dealloc gets called so soon (i.e. after the end of my viewDidLoad method).

Comment: depends on what your doing with the getAll array.  If you are not retaining it (because it's autoreleased), then each Category within the array is going to get a "release" message sent. "release" called on an object with a retain count of 1, will call it's own dealloc method in order to clear itself completely out of memory.  Make sense?

Comment: Yes, this I understand perfectly, but it looks like the objects are deallocated right at the end of -viewDidLoad, but those very elements (description and icon) are used on the screen. So how can they get deallocated and still be visible on my screen??? Does everything get copied somewhere within the magic controller/view realm? ;-)

Comment: Well most likely you are assigning some sort of label on the screen right?  When doing that you are doing this: label.text = category.iconName.  The dealloc is happening on the Category object that has the retain count of 1, not the iconName. The iconName is a string that you simply transferred over to a label's text property.  The Category object has nothing to do with that string member anymore and it's now being retained by the label. The category can be deallocated even though one of it's strings still exists in memory somewhere.

Comment: OK I get it : Category is what is deallocated, which sends a release to the description and iconName properties... and this is not yet the complete release of those elements, just a decrease in their retain count... Thanks a lot! It's getting in!

Comment: 100% correct. The memory management thing clicks one day when seemingly it was a huge mystery the day before. It's best to put the blinders on when thinking about memory. Think very narrowly about when you should retain an object (i.e. when needed outside of current scope) and don't worry about what else is retaining it. Otherwise, toss it. If every object does that, there won't be any leaks.